# How to control, location positions response time frequency from google glass?

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

The response from Google glass location property is very fast. Is it controlable? What is the control point for Google glass location

Comment: Can you clarify if you're trying to do this through the Mirror API or the GDK?

Answer (score 2):

You can't control the frequency of the location callback event.  In my experience if the user is moving around it may fire every few minutes.  If the user does not have their phone paired or on IOS has killed the MyGlass app; then you will not get location data as there will be no GPS info.  If you want more control over frequency of updates you need to build a GDK component and launch it as a service on Glass.

Answer (score 1):

When you are [subscribed to location updates](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/location) on the Mirror API, you will receive location updates at least every 10 minutes, assuming GPS from a paired phone is available.

This 'at least 10 minutes' usually translates to almost exactly every 10 minutes. However, if there is another service on your Glass device that is making more frequent use of location services, such as a background service that pulls the GPS, location updates may be sent by the Mirror API more frequently.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the ability to specify location data update frequency. It is expected that you will get location updates about once every 10 minutes (but maybe more).